# ndisproto sample not reading any traffic

Tags: driver, windows-7-x64, ethernet, ndis

i was trying to get familiar with ndisproto samples in wdk. As per the doc, the `-r -n 10` option should read 10 packets off the interface, but nothing in result even if I ping to the interface! The only time it reads traffic is when we use write option.

The sample is same, without any modification other than altering to `#define NPROTO_PACKET_FILTER  (NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_ALL_LOCAL|NDIS_PACKET_TYPE_PROMISCUOUS)`.

Is the driver really wired to read traffic originating from other sources?

What am I missing? Any idea how to read/sniff the traffic using ndisproto?

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ndisprot>prottest.exe -r -n 10 \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8}
 Option: NumberOfPackets = 10
Trying to access NDIS Device: \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8}
Opened device \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8} successfully!
Trying to get src mac address
GetSrcMac: IoControl success, BytesReturned = 14
Got local MAC: 00:0c:29:23:b1:09
DoReadProc


C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\ndisprot>prottest.exe -w -n 1 \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8}
 Option: NumberOfPackets = 1
Trying to access NDIS Device: \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8}
Opened device \DEVICE\{17152850-6288-471A-9708-2889E7F55EE8} successfully!
Trying to get src mac address
GetSrcMac: IoControl success, BytesReturned = 14
Got local MAC: 00:0c:29:23:b1:09
DoWriteProc
DoWriteProc: sent 100 bytes
DoWriteProc: finished sending 1 packets of 100 bytes each
DoReadProc
DoReadProc: read pkt # 1, 100 bytes
DoReadProc finished: read 1 packets
```

Comment: @jeffrey-tippet Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer at last. The reason is, the driver sample is specifically designed to send/receive `EAP over LAN` frames, not all. There are a couple of break statements in `NdisprotReceiveNetBufferLists` that prevents any other packets other than frames of `ethertype` `0x888E` from reaching the client app.

Same is the case for send.

Comment: Thank you! I had this same problem. For anyone else, just search for NPROT_ETH_TYPE in the driver code and get rid of any checks that exist.